# draw vertical line that match_parent

Tags: android, xml

I created an interface like this

[image]

Here is my XML code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFA5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Team A"
                    android:textColor="#f00"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/team1_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="45sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_3_point_a"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:onClick="threePointA"
                    android:text="+3 Points" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_2_point_a"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:onClick="twoPointA"
                    android:text="+2 Points" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_1_point_a"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:onClick="onePointA"
                    android:text="Free Throw" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="340dp"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:background="#000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Team B"
                    android:textColor="#00f"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/team2_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="45sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_3_point_b"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:onClick="threePointB"
                    android:text="+3 Points" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_2_point_b"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:onClick="twoPointB"
                    android:text="+2 Points" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_1_point_b"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:onClick="onePointB"
                    android:text="Free Throw" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_1_point_b"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="reset"
                android:text="RESET" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

my problem is that I had to hardcoded the "line" between the two scores

```
<View
  android:layout_width="2dp"
  android:layout_height="340dp"
  android:layout_margin="3dp"
  android:background="#000" />
```

Because when i set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` it take the full screen i think it's because the parents height="wrap_content"

Comment: use TextView instead of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFA5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Team A"
                    android:textColor="#f00"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/team1_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="45sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_3_point_a"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:onClick="threePointA"
                    android:text="+3 Points" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_2_point_a"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:onClick="twoPointA"
                    android:text="+2 Points" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_1_point_a"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:onClick="onePointA"
                    android:text="Free Throw" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:background="#000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Team B"
                    android:textColor="#00f"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/team2_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="45sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_3_point_b"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:onClick="threePointB"
                    android:text="+3 Points" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_2_point_b"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:onClick="twoPointB"
                    android:text="+2 Points" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_1_point_b"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:onClick="onePointB"
                    android:text="Free Throw" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_1_point_b"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="reset"
                android:text="RESET" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Make first two Linear Layout wrap_content**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFA5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
```

**And make view match_parent**

```
                <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:background="#000" />
```

Comment: it worked perfectly but i don't understand why the view that we change isn't the parent of the view line,it's on the same level  why did it work ?!

Comment: Your parent view is set as a Match_parent and  child view set as a wrap_content so it's display as a in between two layouts. what is your expected output?

Comment: but the problem was the view that contain the button and the text when, i set the layout_height to wrap_content it solved the problem why when it was match_parent it didn't work ? 
PS: i'm talking about the LinearView that contain the buttons and the text

Answer (score 0):

It's because all your LinearLayout height must be `wrap_content` like :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFA5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Team A"
                    android:textColor="#f00"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/team1_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="45sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_3_point_a"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:onClick="threePointA"
                    android:text="+3 Points" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_2_point_a"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:onClick="twoPointA"
                    android:text="+2 Points" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_1_point_a"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:onClick="onePointA"
                    android:text="Free Throw" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:background="#000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Team B"
                    android:textColor="#00f"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/team2_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="45sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_3_point_b"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:onClick="threePointB"
                    android:text="+3 Points" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_2_point_b"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:onClick="twoPointB"
                    android:text="+2 Points" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_1_point_b"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:onClick="onePointB"
                    android:text="Free Throw" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_1_point_b"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="reset"
                android:text="RESET" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```